# How to set position ellipsis when use -webkit-box?

Tags: html, css

Ellipsis is display in the middle of text, I want it at the end of text like "Text..." Here are my html and css.

```css
.shorten-name {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p class="shorten-name"> VIKTOR & ROLF Wool short design jacket coat Mocha 40</p>
```

[image: output]

Comment: I think that's dependent on the font family you are using. For most of them the horizontal ellipsis is flush with the baseline: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qwgp0eLr/ Works fine for me.

Comment: Default styling is at the end of the text, you have some additional CSS that changes this behaviour.

Comment: I will check again